# Dynamic Tables with Spreadsheet Capabilities in Websites

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, tabular

I'm looking for a way to do spreadsheet type actions with a table on a website that I'm creating. I looked quickly at KendoUI, but that seems to be a little too far out of my budget. Wondering if there was anything cheaper that I could use.

The main features that I'm looking for is to be able to hide columns, filter rows, and row selection via click-drag.

I have very little js experience, but don't mind looking into it to get started. Would need some direction in where to look for that.

The web application is php based, and runs off of the CodeIgniter Framework.

Comment: Have a look at this jQuery plugin: http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery plugin, depending on your need, you will find greats frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of searching and found this one:

http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet